# OOP based syntax to get file’s MIME type

Tags: php, oop, file-upload, upload

I would like to allow users, to upload files to my server, i don't really know the error with this syntax

//EDITED

```
$temp = "file.pdf";
$fileInfo = new finfo;
$getType = $fileInfo->file($temp, FILEINFO_MIME);

$fileExt = array( 'jpg' , 'jpeg' , 'gif' , 'png' , 'zip' , 'rar' , 'pdf' , 'doc' , 'rtf' , 'xls' , 'ppt' , 'odt' , 'ods' );
$ext = strtolower(  substr(  strrchr($temp, '.')  ,1)  );
if(!in_array($ext, $fileExt)) {
    echo "Ext not allowed"
}else {
    if ($getType == "application/pdf" || $getType == "image/png") {
        echo "Ok " .$getType;
    }else {
        echo "No " .$getType;
    }
}
```

Output: No application/pdf;

Any idea ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the above that I can see; what is `finfo`?

Comment: It isn't safe to use the mime type. It is possible to manually encode a MIME message with a forged type that has an undesirable extension (e.g. '.php').

Comment: I also check manually the file extension if(!in_array($ext, $fileExt)) {.... the problem is why i get "No application/pdf;" ?

Comment: The browser my not be sending the proper MIME type. I once wrote a java widget that would upload .ogg files as `application/MyApp` and PHP didn't care one bit. PDF sometimes has the type `application/x-pdf`

Answer (score 1):

It isn't safe to use the mime type. It is possible to manually encode a MIME message with a forged type that has an undesirable extension (e.g. '.php').

Check for the extension instead.

```
$parts = explode('.',$filename);
$ext = array_pop($parts);
if( $ext !='pdf' && $ext !='png')
    return false;
```

Comment: I updated my question, can you code something similar (your way). thanks

Comment: So am I missing something here? a user does upload an exe file by renaming it as .pdf. It's going to show .pdf on the server, so if he tries to access it from a browser, it won't work because it's not a valid pdf - and it won't execute the exe file because it's not an exe file. I'm not sure i understand your solution

Comment: A user can upload a `.php` file with a mime type of `application/pdf`, then access it at `yoursite.com/filename.php`. Your server doesn't care what mime type the file claimed to be, it'll execute any valid PHP in the uploaded file. The file might contain `<?php file_put_contents('index.php', 'You've been hacked'); ?>`

Comment: But this is dangerous, think about it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, may help others.

Use:

`$fileInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);`

`$getType = finfo_file($fileInfo, $temp);`

instead of:

`$fileInfo = new finfo;`

`$getType = $fileInfo->file($temp, FILEINFO_MIME);`